Is Schrodinger's cat a bad analogy?
I have decided to completely revamp and simplify this question in the light of the down votes. The question is simple. What is it about Schrondinger's cat thought experiment, that demonstrates the cat is in a super position of being dead and alive at the same time and not either dead or alive?

All analogies are bad. Some are worse than others.

The Copenhagen interpretation posits collapse. Are you familiar with Bell’s inequalities?

Schrodinger's cat can be applied to each room individually. When you open one room, the wave function in that room collapses to an alive or dead state. The other rooms do not until you open them.

This may help. It explains Shrodinger's cat as background for the Many Worlds interpretation. Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why

If you are uncomfortable with where to draw the line, I suggest not drawing one at all. There is nothing to suggest that the universe's wavefunction has ever collapsed.

@Jbag1212 Yes. I am.

@mmesser314 I was considering the rooms individually. Liked the Veritasium video. Not sure I totally agree with it. It does not describe what happens when for example some of the worlds happen to have correlations that do not agree with quantum mechanics. How are they weeded out or erased?

@mmesser314 As alluded to in my question, a superposition of being dead or alive will have to include a backdated superposition of eaten/uneaten food, used/unused litter tray, O2 consumed/not consumed, CO2 created/not created, air hot/cold etc.

"For example if it half dead you would assume it would only have consumed half of its daily food ration."  And just when I thought I had already seen every possible way to misunderstand quantum mechanics....

@WillO I agree its a misunderstanding of the many worlds interpretation, because when we open the room and make an observation, we only end up in a branch where it was alive all along (and consumed the normal amount of food per day) or in branch where it was dead for a time. In a single world interpretation, it would seem there would be no observable or measurable difference between a cat being in a superposition of being alive and dead at the same time and the cat either being alive or dead, so where is the evidence that the former is more correct than the latter?

@KDP:  You've managed to pack in such a high density of misconceptions per square inch that it's hard to know where to start.  But start here:  There is no such thing, in any interpretation of quantum mechanics, as "half dead".  A cat that is in a non-trivial superposition of "alive" and "dead" eats a non-trivial superposition of all the food and none of the food.   The coefficient on "half the food" is zero.

@WillO You have still avoided stating how the thought experiments proves the cat is in a superposition of alive and dead at the same time and not just in a state of being either alive or dead and we just don't have the information as to which. The former interpretation is an extraordinary claim (in everyday life) and requires an extraordinary proof.

@KDP:  The extraordinary proof is that quantum mechanics makes a vast number of extraordinarily accurate (and experimentally verified) predictions that no other known theory can duplicate.  There are far too many of these to fit in a book, let alone a comment.  If you're asking why we need linear state spaces, the answer is that linear state spaces are at the heart of quantum mechanics; if you didn't have additivity of states, there would be nothing left of the theory.

@WillO   What I am asking is "Is Schrodinger's cat thought experiment unhelpful in demonstrating that an object can be both alive AND dead at the same time, rather than being alive OR dead?" To me, that particular thought experiment fails to give an answer to that particular aspect. A better illustration would be something like a single electron going through two slits at the same time and producing an interference pattern. What I am asking is summarised in the title and everyone is avoiding answering that specific question.

@WillO Spontaneous collapse theories such as suggested by Penrose, would suggest the cat is not in a superposition because the cat is a large object consisting of millions of atoms that are all entangled with each other and the larger the entangled system, the more frequently the wave function collapses, giving macro objects the appearance of having a single state. In those interpretations, the collapse dose not wait until the box is opened and observed by an external observer.

@WillO Consider what happens when we leave a video camera inside the box that records everything the cat does when the box is sealed. I think you will agree that when we open the box and examine the recording, that it won't reveal anything unusual about the state of the cat while the box was sealed. I am pretty sure this is because the video camera is in effect an observer or silent witness and an observer does not need to be sentient. ...

Even if we don't have a video camera inside, the temperature of the air inside the box and the amount of CO2 etc also act as silent witnesses that can reveal the history of what occurred inside the box while it was sealed so the cat and the air molecules become entangled with each other. The air molecules interact with the box and the cat gives off thermal radiation and the walls of the box also give off thermal radiation, so everything inside the box is interacting and entangled with each other...

The atoms that make up the box were once part of an external environment and so they are already entangled with the rest of the universe and even if we somehow suspend the sealed box in a vacuum, the walls remain entangled with the rest of the universe, so the cat is not in an isolated state, and so it is not in a superposition. The cat is also still interacting gravitationally with the rest of the universe. Everything suggests that a large living object cannot be fully isolated from its environment and so cannot be in a state of superposition.

"Is Schrodinger's cat thought experiment unhelpful in demonstrating that an object can be both alive AND dead at the same time, rather than being alive OR dead?"  If you think that a cat can be alive and dead at the same time, then your confusion is about basic logic, not quantum mechanics.  (Though you also seem to think that there is such a thing as a state that is not a superposition, so you've got plenty of problems with QM as well.)

Answer to the revised question:   What demonstrates that the cat is in a (non-trivial) superposition of dead and alive is that it is assumed to be in a non-trivial superposition of dead or alive.   Certain consequences then follow.  Likewise:  My thought-experiment tells me that if I drop a ball off the Empire State building, it will eventually hit the ground.  If I told you about this thought experiment, the question analogous to your current question would be: "What is it about this experiment that demonstrates that you will drop the ball?"

Schrodinger's cat is not an analogy. An analogy is where you say that two different things are similar in some respect. Schrodinger's cat is a thought experiment designed to make a point. That is not the same as an analogy.
When we try to explain the behaviour of small systems like atoms we use quantum theory, which explains atomic orbitals in terms of quantum interference between different versions of an electron. The electron has an unsharp position and momentum and if you measure either the position or the momentum with enough precision you will find it has multiple possible values with different probabilities.
When we see objects like cats in everyday life we only see one version of the cat.
But this creates a problem. If the cat is made up of particles that exist in multiple versions, then there should be multiple versions of the cat. The Schrodinger's cat thought experiment highlights this problem by coupling the cat directly to an atom that exists in multiple versions.
Physicists have suggested multiple solutions to this problem.
Some physicists say we should ignore it: advocates of the Copenhagen and statistical interpretations of quantum theory. This has the obvious disadvantage of ignoring a problem with a fundamental theory in physics that could lead to deeper understanding of the theory or replacing it with a better theory. They also have the problem that they say it is impossible to understand experiments and so to check whether they have been done properly.
Some physicists have suggested modifying quantum theory, e.g. pilot wave and spontaneous collapse theories:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10761
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
It should be noted that pilot wave and spontaneous collapse theories can't currently reproduce the predictions of quantum field theories that are used to make the vast bulk of actual predictions made using quantum theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
You could also take the equations of quantum theory as a description of how reality works and works out their consequences. When you do this, you find that quantum theory explains that when information is copied out of a system while it's undergoing interference, the interference is suppressed, this is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
As a result of this process, on the scale of everyday life reality as described by quantum theory looks a bit like a collection of parallel universes:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
Physicists often call this the many worlds interpretation (MWI).
You asked:

Where do we draw the line between particles that can be in a superposition and macro objects that cannot?

If we take quantum theory seriously as a description of how the world works, we don't draw the line: the cat is in a decoherent superposition. Advocates of the Copenhagen and statistical interpretation draw the line in an ad hoc unexplained way. The pilot wave theory claims the cat is made of particles that were always in a particular place. Advocates of spontaneous collapse theories say the cat is so large that it almost certainly collapses to only one version.
